# Jenkins - Difference between "Build With Params" and "Build with Parameters"?

Tags: jenkins

There are radio buttons for choice(selection) in "Build with Parameters" but its not available in "Build With Params", and there is another option for "Rebuild Last"(which is quite understandable).
but what is actual difference between these "Build With Params" and  "Build with Parameters" ?

Thanks

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Some screenshots would be nice, but to answer your question - refer to this conversation: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/n4gExNblico).

I haven't seen this before, so my guess would be that another plugin adds this view. Or maybe different ( older / newer ) Jenkins version.

Looks like Jenkins itself adds 'Build with params', but Parametrized trigger plugin also adds 'Build with parameters'. If you used Parametrized trigger plugin then 'Build with parameters' is the correct option, since even if 'Build with params' works this way - you still won't have 100% confidence that legacy will support the features in 'Parametrized trigger plugin'.